# Why (( and [[ return different result with same expression

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

  main () {
    # your main function code here
    if (($# != 2)); then
        echo "Usage: hamming.sh <string1> <string2>"
        exit 1
    fi

    if (("${#1}" != "${#2}")); then
        echo "strands must be of equal length"
        exit 1
    fi

    COUNT=0
    for (( i=0; i < ${#1}; i++ ));
    do
     [[ "${1:$i:1}" != "${2:$i:1}" ]] && COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))

#    (( "${1:$i:1}" != "${2:$i:1}" )) && COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
    done
    echo $COUNT
  }

  # call main with all of the positional arguments
  main "$@"
```

When i try to run with

1. 'AAA' 'A?A': The "[[...]]" will return 1 but the "((...))" return error:

   line 35: ((: A != ? : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "? ")
2. 'GGACGGATTCTG' 'AGGACGGATTCT': The "[[...]]" will return 9 but the "((...))" return 0

Why this happen with same expression?

Comment: See ["What is the difference between the Bash operators `[[` vs `[` vs `(` vs `((`?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double parentheses expression is for math calculation, e.g.

```
$ echo $(( 2 + 4 ))
6

$ a=3
$ (( a++ ))
$ echo $a
4
```

While double square brackets carry condition check, e.g.

```
$ if [[ $x == $y ]]; then echo x equals y; fi
x equals y

$ if [[ a < b ]]; then echo a is lexicographically smaller than b; fi
a is lexicographically smaller than b
```

So essentially ((..)) and [[..]] are not interchangeable.

Comment: Very kind answer where others would just post a pejorative comment and close the question. Keep that up! ... Aaaanyways: You can find the official documentation directly in your bash shell by running `help "(("` or `help "[["`. Sorry, could not resist :)

Comment: Also, the operators are different between `(( ))` and `[[ ]]`. For example, in `(( ))`, the `=` operator does assignment, but in `[[ ]]` it does comparison for textual equality.